# Android Parse how can I use getObjectId(); when setting a ParseUser object?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, onclick

I have a user search and a listview to populate with the results. The results have an "Add Friend" button.

This is what I have for the onClick:

```
OnClickListener addRequest = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        userConnection = new UserConnection();
        userConnection.setCurrentUser(User.getCurrentUser());
        userConnection.setOtherUser(users.get(position).getObjectId()); ////HELP, this is where I need to get the objectId for the user and set it as OtherUser
        userConnection.setFriendRequestStatus(appConstants.FRIENDREQUESTSTATUS.PENDING);
        userConnection.setCurrentUserSentRequest(true);
        Utils.showOKdialog(context, "Press OK to send friend request");
        userConnection.saveInBackground();

        Log.d(TAG, "You have sent a friend request to " + userConnection.getOtherUser().getLastName() + " " + userConnection.getOtherUser().getFirstName());

    }
};
```

I have a comment on which line I need help with, the problem I am having is .getObjectId returns a String and .setOtheruser calls for a ParseUser. Any ideas on how to get the objectId which is a String on the user that is at the position of the list view clicked?

I also tried this but it came back with a null reference for .getParseUser("objectId")

```
userConnection.setOtherUser(users.get(position).getParseUser("objectId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, I was making things too complicated as usual. The solution is just

```
userConnection.setOtherUser(users.get(position));
```